# html.actionlink with .net 4.0 renders empty links

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, actionlink

This should hopefully be a simple configuration problem.

When my application targets .Net 3.5

This code

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?","ForgotPassword") %>
```

renders this:

```
<a href="/Account/ForgotPassword">Forgot your password?</a>
```

When my application targets .Net 4.0

The same code renders:

```
<a href="">Forgot your password?</a>
```

It's dropping the url part.

backwards compatibility is supposedly enabled in my web.config.

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This had to do with the default map route having an extra value.  It looks like .Net 4.0 is less forgiving about bad path mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the following issues is very small. Please check your global.asax.cs file and change the line

```
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } // Parameter defaults
```

to

```
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
```

Note: in MVC2.0 optional fields are marked through "UrlParameter.Optional".

I think this may solve your issues. If not then please update.

Thanks,

Kamal Kant Pansari